# Overflow scroll without specifying height?

Tags: html, css

In my app targeting mobile devices (with cordova but that shouldn't matter) 
I want to show a scrolling div that fills the page except for a top and bottom navbar:
[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JbkGe/)

As far as I understand, I need to specify the height of the div in order for the div to scroll. (line 30 in the css - currently commented out):

```
#long {

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue);
width: 90%;

/* scroll */
overflow-y: scroll;
/* for the navbar */
margin-top: 48px;
float: left;
/* to make the scroll work */
/*height: 347px;*/
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

}
```

I would really prefer if I would have to because using discrete intervals for media queries will always risk some obscurely sized phones to have broader bottom margins than intended.

An additional requirements that might constrain potential solutions:
- The app has several "pages" which are div's that are moved out of the viewport to the left or right when not needed but not removed from the document.

Any ideas how to solve this? Preferably using only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If the page fit the viewport dimensions, I’d create a wrapper with some padding to position the navbar absolutely and then make an inner container scroll. This will always fit the viewport height and so doesn’t require a fixed height.

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 48px; // Allow space for navbar
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.navbar {
  height: 48px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

The HTML would look like:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="navbar"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LeBen/dN3g5/)

Comment: Sadly, the content is flowing out of the div at the bottom and is not visible there.

Comment: @DanSchien I think you can fix that by replacing `.inner height` with ```height: calc(100% - 48px);```